# Why is my code printing every number?

Tags: c++, arrays, average

I have written this code that reads 10 integers from the user, stores them in an array, then calculates and prints the average. It is also supposed to print the numbers in the array that are greater than or equal to the average. Instead, my code prints out every number in the array. How can I fix this?

Also, if anyone has any tips on how to simplify this code, that would be much appreciated, as well.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ENTER_NUM = 10;
    int integer[ENTER_NUM];

    cout << "Enter "<<ENTER_NUM<<" numbers: "<<endl;
    cin >> integer[0];
    cin >> integer[1];
    cin >> integer[2];
    cin >> integer[3];
    cin >> integer[4];
    cin >> integer[5];
    cin >> integer[6];
    cin >> integer[7];
    cin >> integer[8];
    cin >> integer[9];

    int sum;
    sum = integer[0]+integer[1]+integer[2]+integer[3]+integer[4]+integer[5]+integer[6]+integer[7]+integer[8]+integer[9];

    int average;
    average = sum/ENTER_NUM;

    cout<<"Average is: "<<average<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
            if (integer[i]>=average);
            cout<<"Number in array greater than or equal to the average: "<<integer[i]<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: line 23 continues as +integer[7]+integer[8]+integer[9];

Comment: Side note: it seems that you already know about loops; so why do use a loop to compare against average; but write down all the array elements manually when computing the initial sum? That's like ... well, not very clever.

Comment: You should read up on `std::vector`, `std::accumulate` or more generally the standard library.

Comment: A `for` loop can be used to input data as well!  Another one to calculate the sum.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- or the same one to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (integer[i]>=average);` contains a semicolon at the end, removing its ability to control the print statement after it. Turn up the warning level on your compiler and you'd have a message about this

Answer (score 5):

You have a spurious `;` after the `if` in the loop.

When you always use `{}` on `if`s and similar control structures instead of relying on the "one line exception", this error is less likely to happen.